# Can prestashop be installed as an extension in Joomla in my webserver?

Tags: prestashop

Or is prestashop sufficient enough so that I don't need any CMS tool alongwith it?I am just ignorant about how prestashop works.In its website there is nowhere mentioned that it has to be installed with some other CMS tool...Please help...

Answer (score 2):

There is a prestashop component for Joomla 2.5 that you can install to an existing Joomla 2.5 installation. Prestashop is fully integrated with all its features and addons. It comes ou-of-the-box with shared login and can be installed in 2 minutes.

You can view an online demo at http://prestashop-joomla.com/online-demo/

The site is http://prestashop-joomla.com

Enjoy...

Answer (score 0):

If someone writes the code for it, maybe. At this time don't know any extension for Joomla. Prestashop is a standalone package. It would be great... but I'm not aware of it.